# sinon stub is not working

Tags: testing, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I'm quiet new into testing and I don't seem to succeed to succesfully stub a function. I'm trying to stub the connection to the database, but it keep's contacting it, instead of using the result from the stub:

Here's the function:

```
var self = module.exports = {
VerifyAuthentication: function (data){      
    var deferred = q.defer()                
    if(typeof(data.email)=='undefined'){
        deferred.reject({data:{},errorcode:"",errormessage:"param 'email' is mandatory in input object"})
    }else{
        if(typeof(data.password)=='undefined'){
            deferred.reject({data:{},errorcode:"",errormessage:"param 'password' is mandatory in input object"})
        }else{
            var SqlString = "select id, mail, password, origin from tbl_user where mail = ?"    
            var param = [data.email]
            self.ExecuteSingleQuery(SqlString, param).then(function(results){   
                if(results.length > 0)
                {
                    if (results[0].password == data.password)
                    {                   
                        deferred.resolve({data:{"sessionId":results[0].id},errorcode:"",errormessage:""})
                    }else{              
                        deferred.reject({data:{},errorcode:"",errormessage:"bad password"})
                    }
                }else{
                    deferred.reject({data:{},errorcode:"",errormessage:"unknown user"})
                }
            })
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise
},
ExecuteSingleQuery: function (queryString, parameters){     
    var deferred = q.defer()        
    var connection = connect()

    connection.query(queryString, parameters, function (error, results, fields){
        if(error){ deferred.reject(error)};     
        deferred.resolve(results)
    });

    return deferred.promise
},
```

And here's the test:

```
var dbconnection = require('../lib/dbConnection.js') 
describe("VerifyAuthentication", function(){
    it("_Returns DbResult object when user name and password match", function(){
        var expectedResult = {data:{"sessionKey":"b12ac0a5-967e-40f3-8c4d-aac0f98328b2"},errorcode:"",errormessage:""}
        stub = sinon.stub(dbconnection, 'ExecuteSingleQuery').returns(Promise.resolve(expectedResult))
        return dbconnection.VerifyAuthentication({email:"correct@adres.com",password:"gtffr"}).then((result)=>{
            expect(result.data.sessionId).to.not.be.undefined
            expect(result.errorcode).to.not.be.undefined
            expect(result.errormessage).to.not.be.undefined
            stub.restore()                
        })
    })  
})
```

I always got an error 'unknown user', which is normal, because the user is indeed not in the database. However, I want to stub the 'ExecuteSingleQuery' function, avoiding it to connect to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed a couple of issues in your code and posting the corrected files below.

### dbConnection.js

```
var self = module.exports = {
    VerifyAuthentication: function (data) {
        var deferred = q.defer();

        if (typeof (data.email) == 'undefined') {
            deferred.reject({
                data: {},
                errorcode: '',
                errormessage: "param 'email' is mandatory in input object"
            });
        } else {
            if (typeof (data.password) == 'undefined') {
                deferred.reject({
                    data: {},
                    errorcode: '',
                    errormessage: "param 'password' is mandatory in input object"
                });
            } else {
                var SqlString = 'select id, mail, password, origin from tbl_user where mail = ?';
                var param = [data.email];

                self.ExecuteSingleQuery(SqlString, param).then(function (results) {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        if (results[0].password === data.password) {
                            deferred.resolve({
                                data: {
                                    'sessionId': results[0].id
                                },
                                errorcode: '',
                                errormessage: ''
                            });
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject({
                                data: {},
                                errorcode: '',
                                errormessage: 'bad password'
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject({
                            data: {},
                            errorcode: '',
                            errormessage: 'unknown user'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    ExecuteSingleQuery: function (queryString, parameters) {
        var deferred = q.defer();
        var connection = connect();

        connection.query(queryString, parameters, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            deferred.resolve(results);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

### dbConnection.test.js

```
describe('VerifyAuthentication', function () {
    it('Returns DbResult object when user name and password match', function () {
        var expectedResult = [{
            id: '123',
            password: 'gtffr'
        }];

        const stub = sinon.stub(dbconnection, 'ExecuteSingleQuery').resolves(expectedResult);

        return dbconnection.VerifyAuthentication({
            email: 'correct@adres.com',
            password: 'gtffr'
        }).then((result) => {
            expect(result.data.sessionId).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(result.errorcode).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(result.errormessage).to.not.be.undefined;
            stub.restore();
        });
    });
});
```

I am outlining the problematic parts below:

- The **expectedResult** variable had a wrong type of value.  In the 
  **self.ExecuteSingleQuery()** implementation you check for an array with length > 0.  The fixed result returned by the stub, was an object instead of an array and this is why it returned the **unknown user** exception
- The array should contain an object with `{ id: 'xxx', password: 'gtffr' }` attributes.  Password is validated against the one used by the `dbconnection.VerifyAuthentication({email:"correct@adres.com",password:"gtffr"})` call
- Finally, I have changed the stub statement to **resolve** instead of **return** as shown here `const stub = sinon.stub(dbconnection, 'ExecuteSingleQuery').resolves(expectedResult);` - this is the preferred method of resolving a promise

Comment: Thanks, I now can see my confusion. My expected result was not what I expected from 'ExecuteSingleQuery', but what is expected from VerifyAuthentication. It took me some time to see this, but thanks to you I found it out.
Thanks for the hint on 'resolves'